# How to solve Invalid MEX file error In Matlab?

Tags: windows, matlab, 32bit-64bit, mex

Every time I try to define a symbolic variable I get this error message

> Invalid MEX-file 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\toolbox\symbolic\symbolic\mupadmex.mexw64':
>   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\toolbox\symbolic\symbolic\mupadmex.mexw64 is not a valid Win32 application.

please help :)

Comment: you cannot just copy over files from a Win64 installation of MATLAB into a Win32 one (especially native binaries like DLLs and MEX-files). You should reinstall MATLAB on your machine (the installer will pick the right files automatically).

Answer (score 1):

`.mexw64` is the file extension for mex files that have been compiled for 64-bit systems.

If your Windows installation is 32 bit,  or even if Windows is 64-bit but the *Matlab* install is 32-bit (check the task manager to verify the latter) then Matlab will be looking for `.mexw32` files, compiled for 32-bit systems, instead.  The message "...is not a valid Win32 application" seems to imply that this is the case.  If so, you need to obtain or build a 32-bit version of your mex file.

Answer (score 1):

This error is caused by missing lib. Please install lib based on link as below:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14632
Or
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15336

Answer (score 0):

this problem seemed independent of 32/64 bit machines or versions of windos to me. I could solve it several times by simply installing the 2012 or a higher version of Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable.